# RecyclerView app crash

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, layout-inflater

I have a problem when I'm trying to use a `RecyclerView`. The app crashes directly on launch.

Here is the error in logcat:

```
`Process: com.test.alvar.temadagar, PID: 14522
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.alvar.temadagar/com.test.alvar.temadagar.Temadagar}   : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #182: Error   inflating class RecyclerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #182: Error inflating class RecyclerView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
        at com.test.alvar.temadagar.Temadagar.onCreate(Temadagar.java:73)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.RecyclerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.alvar.temadagar-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.test.alvar.temadagar-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
at com.test.alvar.temadagar.Temadagar.onCreate(Temadagar.java:73)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

</pre>
```

Temadagar.java (Main activity)

```
package com.test.alvar.temadagar;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityOptionsCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

public class Temadagar extends AppCompatActivity {


private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_temadagar);
    StrictMode.enableDefaults(); //STRICT MODE ENABLED


    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getDataSet());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((MyRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setOnItemClickListener(new
         MyRecyclerViewAdapter.MyClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
                 // Log.i(LOG_TAG, " Clicked on Item " + position);
             }
         });
}

private ArrayList<DataObject> getDataSet() {
    ArrayList results = new ArrayList<DataObject>();
    for (int index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
        DataObject obj = new DataObject("Some Primary Text " + index,
                "Secondary " + index);
        results.add(index, obj);
    }

    return results;
}

}
```

DataObject.java

```
package com.test.alvar.temadagar;

public class DataObject {

private String mText1;
private String mText2;

DataObject (String text1, String text2){
    mText1 = text1;
    mText2 = text2;
}

public String getmText1() {
    return mText1;
}

public void setmText1(String mText1) {
    this.mText1 = mText1;
}

public String getmText2() {
    return mText2;
}

public void setmText2(String mText2) {
    this.mText2 = mText2;
}
}
```

MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
package com.test.alvar.temadagar;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView
    .Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter
    .DataObjectHolder> {
private static String LOG_TAG = "MyRecyclerViewAdapter";
private ArrayList<DataObject> mDataset;
private static MyClickListener myClickListener;

public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View
        .OnClickListener {
    TextView label;
    TextView dateTime;

    public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        label = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        dateTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myClickListener.onItemClick(getPosition(), v);
    }
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
    this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
}

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<DataObject> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

@Override
public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

    DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
    return dataObjectHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.label.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText1());
    holder.dateTime.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText2());
}

public void addItem(DataObject dataObj, int index) {
    mDataset.add(dataObj);
    notifyItemInserted(index);
}

public void deleteItem(int index) {
    mDataset.remove(index);
    notifyItemRemoved(index);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

public interface MyClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
}
}
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_temdagar.xml (main)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/coming_text"
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use `<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` in your `activity_temdagar.xml`, not `<RecyclerView`. The widget is only part of the support library

Comment: Okay, the app does not crash anymore. But there is no data in the RecyclerView, can't see it

Comment: get rid of `android:layout_below="@+id/coming_text"`. And in list_item.xml make `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` instead of `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: and get rid of `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` too